# c# close process sending message with CloseReason

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process

I need to close a process defining a particular CloseReason, this due that the process that I need to kill check in the form closing if the CloseReasonis a WindowsShutDown it close the program, otherwise no:

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown)
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
  }
}
```

but if from another program I do this:

```
List<Process> pp = Process.GetProcessesByName("myProgram").ToList();
foreach (var p in pp)
{
  p.CloseMainWindow();
  p.WaitForExit();
}
```

but the program is not closed....

how can I do this?

Comment: What is the value of `e.CloseReason` when running the code you posted?

Comment: You can probably send a WM_ENDSESSION window message.

Comment: use `SendMessage` to send `WM_CLOSE` with custom `lParam` and handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot explicitly set the close reason for the Process.Kill or CloseMainWindow() . The following are the close reasons available, you can chose appropriate reasons

- `ApplicationExitCall`    The Exit method of the Application class was
  invoked.
- `FormOwnerClosing`   The owner form is closing.
- `MdiFormClosing` The parent form of this multiple document interface
  (MDI) form is closing.
- `None`   The cause of the closure was not defined or could not be
  determined.
- `TaskManagerClosing` The Microsoft Windows Task Manager is closing
  the application.
- `UserClosing`    The user is closing the form through the user interface
  (UI), for example by clicking the Close button on the form window,
  selecting Close from the window's control menu, or pressing ALT+F4.
- `WindowsShutDown`    The operating system is closing all applications
  before shutting down.

Comment: thanks, but the Process.Kill can't pass through the frmMain_FormClosing